# exists?() with OR condition Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to find whether a user with `first_name` **OR** `last_name` as 'john' exists in the database or not. 
Is it possible with using **single** `exists?()`? Something like `User.exists?("first_name='john' OR last_name = 'john'")`

My current approach is:

```
User.where("first_name = ? OR last_name = ?", 'john', 'john').any?
```

Another approach could be using `.count`.

Comment: "my current approach is ..." - what happens if you simply use `.exists?` instead of `.any?` there?

Comment: .exists? will also return true and false

Comment: So, no difference, problem solved?

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev that's true, which approach is better? where('...').exists? or exists?([...])

Comment: Neither is "better'.

Comment: Please suggest a better way.

Comment: Better for what metric? These are good enough.

Answer (score 4):

if you want any one of the condition to be true then use this

```
User.exists?(['first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ?', 'john', 'john'])
```

if you want both condition to be true you can use this code

```
User.exists?(first_name: 'john', last_name: 'john')
```